# how to use extern in C?

Tags: c, compilation, declaration, extern

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int x;
void a() {
    int x = 100;
    printf("%d ",x );
    x += 5;
}

void b() {
    static int x = -10;
    printf("%d ", x);
    x += 5;
}

void c(){
    printf("%d ", x);
    x += 2;
}

int main() {
    int x = 10;
    a();
    b();
    c();
    a();
    b();
    c();
    printf("%d ", x);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int x = 0;
```

I was sure that the fact that extern in declared here, I will have a compilation error - but everything passed.
also , what is the meaning of extern when it's inside the C file itself? shouldn't it be in another file?
Is there a way to declare this variable in order for this not to compile?

Comment: Since all your code is in one file, the `extern` doesn't do anything, it's just a hint that the variable may be defined in another file. If not then it's just a normal global variable.

Comment: There's some recent discussion about this question on comp.lang.c; Google Groups version [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.lang.c/6kfYpdjBr6g).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `extern` keyword declares a variable, and tells the compiler there is a definition for it elsewhere. In the case of the posted code, the definition of `x` occurs after `main()`. If you remove the `int x = 0;` after `main()` the code will not build (it will compile but will fail to link due to undefined symbol `x`).

`extern` is commonly used to declare variables (or functions) in header files and have the definition in a separate source (`.c`) file to make the same variable available to multiple translation units (and avoid multiple definition errors):

```
/* my.h */
#ifndef MY_HEADER
#define MY_HEADER
extern int x;
#endif

/* my.c */
#include "my.h"
int x = 0;
```

Note that the declaration of `x` in functions `a()`, `b()` and `main()` hide the global variable `x`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a declaration for an identifier at file scope, so if no other declaration for the identifier would've been existing at file scope, the identifier would have had and *external linkage.* But, you've defined the identifier at file scope at the last line, in the pasted code.

So,`extern int x;`

refers to the globally defined: `int x = 0;` at the bottom of your file. :)

If you run this code you should get **x**'s value as 2 and subsequently 4 because the externed x variable refers to the *int x=0* after the main().

Answer (score 0):

Extern is used for declaration a variable in a compilation unit, this variable was defined in other compilation unit.

[What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

For functions it is optional.

Read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable

In your piece of code, each of the three function uses another 'i'. Only c() uses the global x.